# Gradle - get artifact from repository and use it

Tags: jar, gradle, artifact

#### The problem:

I have a jar in some repository. 
I want to run the jar and do something with it during gradle task.

#### The attempt:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  maven {
    url "<<<valid repo url>>>"
  }
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile(group: 'com.google.developers', name: 'compiler', version: 'v20150315', ext: 'pom')
}

task doTheJar {
  dependsOn configurations.compile
  exec {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c","java -jar <<the-artifact>> smoething something"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do it? 
Is there a way to do it without java plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better to do it in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  maven {
    url "<<<valid repo url>>>"
  }
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
   runjar
}

dependencies {
  runjar 'some:artifact:1.0'
}

task runTheJar(type: JavaExec) {
   main 'main.class.to.be.run'
   classpath configurations.runjar
   args 's1', 's2', 's3'
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfect. Any way to do it without java plugin?

Comment: It's possible but problematic, why you need to eliminate java plugin?

Comment: Lest say that instead of a jar there is a zip file or an executable sh file or a binary executable or some other resource file. Java plugin elimination issue is just curiosity.

Comment: If you have all the artifacts (I mean classpath jar) it can be done with just executing os command with `Exec` task. With `JavaExec` handling classpath is just much easier. If the problem is solved, please accept the answer.